# What can I pass to fopen?

Tags: c, file-handling

Can I pass a character array to `fopen`? For example:

```
    fopen(s, "r");
```

Where `s` is declared as a character array and is null terminated.

Comment: `s` may be whatever you want if it represents NUL-terminated sequence of `char`.

Comment: When you pass a variable to a function, you have to keep two things in mind -- the type of the variable and the value of the variable. A char array is good for the type. It is not enough. Its value has to be set appropriately.

Comment: Read the manual... google... anything. It's not difficult research.

Comment: Maybe RTFM would help? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: @Jay Khandkar: "null voided"? What does that mean?

Comment: Of course, a file opened for reading must exist. You assign the return value from `fopen` to a `FILE *` variable, and you must check it is not `NULL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the file named doesn't have to exist to be passed to `fopen()` — it has to exist to be opened successfully for reading, but that's different.  The argument to `fopen()` should be a valid (non-null) pointer to a null-terminated string.  Lots of strings that could be passed won't be valid and the `fopen()` call will therefore fail.

Comment: Is there any other C function that often and well documented like `fopen` in the internet? (ok, maybe `printf`). What did you try to find out` Why does that not work? Did you read what a C-string is?

Comment: Detail: Code cannot pass an array.  Instead with `char s[100]; ... fopen(s, "r");`, code passed the address of `s[0]` to `fopen()`.  That _pointer_ needs to point to a sequence of characters that end with a null character.

Comment: @chux: Nitpicking on the detail: The pointer needs to point to `char`. IIRC, `wchar_t` is also a character type;-)

Comment: @Oalf "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of _characters_ terminated by and including the first null character.". 7.1.1 1.  Seems the spec uses _character_ in this narrow context.   `wchar_t` represents extended characters.  7.19 2.  and uses _wide string_ in that context.

Comment: @AnT Sorry, I meant null terminated

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you nit-picking too? The question of nul termination had already been answered. I was commenting on the `fopen(s, "r");` posted being inadequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` must be a pointer to a null terminated character array.[image]

The [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) confirm this

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

You can see that it must be null terminated, since no `size` argument is given.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) is:

```
FILE * fopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode );
```

So the `filename` parameter has to be a valid C string. That's all.

Comment: Strictly speaking it expects a pointer, not a C string, which is an array of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The exact signature for `fopen` as specified ni the C11 Standard is:

```
FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode);
```

Both `filename` and `mode` are just pointers to null terminated arrays of `char` (*aka C strings*).

The presence of the `restrict` keyword seems to indicate that the strings should not overlap, which does not make much sense since they are both `const` qualified.

When you pass a `char` array to `fopen`, a pointer to its first element is passed.  This step is referred to as *the array decays into a pointer*.  The same happens whenever an array is used in an expression, except as an argument to `sizeof`.